# Received authentication null when trying to follow a user using twitter4j-4.0.1

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to create an app which requires me to have follow button so that user can follow my screenname on twitter.

I can make user log in to their user account and post however when I am trying to make then follow my screen name, Logcat shows me " Received authentication challenge is null" however I am using the same Twitter object which I made while trying to login.

I am pasting the code below

```
 static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "LsCQaPOwd8k7WkyRFRZF4Q";
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "KJbJu5IQrlwxW7Cwnax3mMzAc4j3n6Wd2dG125srgk";

// Preference Constants
static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

// Twitter oauth urls
static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

Button btnLoginTwitter;
// Update status button
Button btnUpdateStatus;
// Logout button
Button btnLogoutTwitter;
// EditText for update
EditText txtUpdate;
// lbl update
TextView lblUpdate;
TextView lblUserName;
Button follow;
// Progress dialog
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Twitter
private static Twitter twitter;
private static RequestToken requestToken;
private AccessToken accessToken;
private User user;

// Shared Preferences
private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

// Internet Connection detector
private ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error", "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if twitter keys are set
    if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // All UI elements
    btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
    btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
    btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
    follow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.followTwitter);
    txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
    lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
    lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

    // Shared Preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

    /**
     * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
     * */
    btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call login twitter function
            loginToTwitter();
        }
    });

    follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           new FollowFriend().execute();

        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
     * function
     * */
    btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call update status function
            // Get the status from EditText
            String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

            // Check for blank text
            if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                // update status
                new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
            } else {
                // EditText is empty
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter status message", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event for logout from twitter
     * */
    btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call logout twitter function
            logoutFromTwitter();
        }
    });

    /** This if conditions is tested once is
     * redirected from twitter page. Parse the uri to get oAuth
     * Verifier
     * */
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {

            // oAuth verifier
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
            new OAuthAccessTokenTask().execute(verifier);
        }
    }

}
 class FollowFriend extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
 {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         try {

                twitter.createFriendship("xyz");
             System.out.println("Successfully followed ");
         } catch (TwitterException te) {
             te.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Failed to follow: " + te.getMessage());


         }
        return null;
    }

 }
 private class OAuthAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Exception>
 {
    @Override
    protected Exception doInBackground(String... params) {
        Exception toReturn = null;

        try {
            accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, params[0]);
            user = twitter.showUser(accessToken.getUserId());

        }
        catch(TwitterException e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(), "TwitterError: " + e.getErrorMessage());
            toReturn = e;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            toReturn = e;
        }

        return toReturn;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception exception) {
        onRequestTokenRetrieved(exception);
    }
 }

 private void onRequestTokenRetrieved(Exception result) {

     if (result != null) {
         Toast.makeText(
                 this, 
                 result.getMessage(), 
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                 ).show();
     }

     else {
         try {
             // Shared Preferences
             Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

             // After getting access token, access token secret
             // store them in application preferences
             editor.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
             editor.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                     accessToken.getTokenSecret());
             // Store login status - true
             editor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
             editor.commit(); // save changes

             Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

             // Hide login button
             btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

             // Show Update Twitter
             lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             follow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             // Getting user details from twitter
             String username = user.getName();

             // Displaying in xml ui
             lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
             // Check log for login errors
             Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + ex.getMessage());
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }

/**
 * Function to login twitter
 * */
private void loginToTwitter() {
    // Check if already logged in
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();


            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();         
    } else {
        // user already logged into twitter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Function to update status
 * */
class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
        String status = args[0];
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token 
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
     * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
     * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Clearing EditText field
                txtUpdate.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Function to logout from twitter
 * It will just clear the application shared preferences
 * */
private void logoutFromTwitter() {
    // Clear the shared preferences
    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
    e.commit();

    // After this take the appropriate action
    // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
    // You might not needed this code
    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUserName.setText("");
    lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
 * fetched from Shared Preferences
 * */
private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
    // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
    return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try in normal away first as :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    /**
     * Function to login twitter
     * */
    private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
//      if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();


                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();         
//      } else {
//          // user already logged into twitter
//          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//      }
    }


    public void btnAdd_Click(View v) {
        loginToTwitter();

    }

    public void btnAdd2_Click(View v) {
           try {
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                twitter.createFriendship("Dan");
                System.out.println("Successfully followed [Dan].");
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (TwitterException te) {
                te.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to follow: " + te.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }

    }
```

Comment: That will give Network on Main thread exception cause I am testing on android device which has Android 4.0 and above...Let me put your code in asynctask and check!!hold on!!!

Comment: you got the error^, because permissions, add these to manifest http://pastebin.com/ndunJnMn